# Android L support library Toolbar appears under views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

I have a mainactivity.xml that has a framelayout and inside that has a toolbar

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside my mainactivity.java, I have this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

Based on the tutorial here, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html, I should have a custom Toolbar that acts as an actionbar. However, the toolbar that appears happens under the fragments that I add in the block. The toolbar is supposed to appear above them and shift them downwards, but now the views cover the actionbar toolbar. Is this a glitch or am I simply forgetting something? This actually worked before but is now broken for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toolbar` needs to be outside of the `FrameLayout` that is going to hold your `Fragment` like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```